# Sending mail with PHP throught XAMPP localhost (No email send) (begginner)

Tags: php, html, xampp

I have this code for html form:

```html
<form name="form1" method="post" action="C:/xampp/htdocs/shangri_la/contacto.php">
      <p>
        <label>Nombre
          <input name="nombre" type="text" id="nombre" size="35">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Correo a responder
          <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label>Mensaje
          <br>
          <textarea name="textarea" cols="100" rows="15" id="textarea"></textarea>
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Enviar">
      </p>
    </form>
```

And this for the php:

```html
< ?php 
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];

$header = 'From: ' . $mail . " \r\n";
$header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . " \r\n";
$header .= "Mime-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain";

$mensaje = "De " . $nombre . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Responder a: " . $mail . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['mensaje'] . " \r\n";
$mensaje .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

$para = 'my-email';
$asunto = 'Mensaje de pagina principal';

mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);

echo 'Mensaje enviado correctamente';

?>
```

The problem is that I run the code and it sends me directly to a page with the php code which is the same result I received withouth XAMPP. I already change all I could find about the sendmail function in XAMPP and the php.ini. So, can someone help me identify if there is an error in the code, if the error might be in the server settings or if there is another server option I can use?

XAMPP php.ini:

```html
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = my@mail.com
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = “\”C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\” -t”
```

XAMPP sendmail.ini:

```html
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
smtp_ssl=ssl
default_domain=localhost
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my@mail.com
auth_password=*******
force_sender=admin
hostname=localhost
```

Comment: The opening php tag should be `<?php` instead of `< ?php`.

Comment: @pgnp That surely helped, now the server recognices de php but the button still does nothing.

Comment: Are you sure the php file path in `action` is correct? I copied the code on my machine and when I clicked on the button, the php code got executed.